# How to upload image file in the request body with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, http, networking, upload, alamofire

I'm new to iOS development, and right now I'm writing an app using Alamofire to upload image to server, but after hours of looking for solutions and reading documentation, I still have not made it work yet. Can someone please help? Thanks. This is my code so far:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        //Upload image from here
        //Get user for header info
        var user = User.getUserInstance()

        //Get current patient for header info
        var currentPatient = CurrentPatient.getCurrentPatientInstance()

        //Server address
        let serverAddress = user.serverAddress

        //Prep for headers
        var headers = [
            "ISHC_LOGIN": user.username,
            "ISHC_PWD": user.password,
            "ISHC_API_TOKEN":"token",
            "ISHC_OPERATION":"CreateImage",
            "ISHC_IMAGE_NAME":"test",
            "ISHC_EXTAPP_ID":"app",    
            "ISHC_FOLDER_ID":currentPatient.getCurrentPatient().patientID,
            "ISHC_EXTAPP_VALUE":"IS_WEB_STAGE", 
            "Accept-Encoding": "application/xml"
        ]

        print("UPLOADING...")

       let request = Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
            multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
               // multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)

        }, to: serverAddress, method: .post, headers: headers,
                encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.response { [weak self] response in
                            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                                return
                            }
                            debugPrint("RESPONSE IS:\(response)")
                        }
                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                        print("error:\(encodingError)")
                    }
        })
        debugPrint("request is:\(request)")
    }
```

Based on the API (I'm only the front-end dev), I can upload the image using the request body and can keep the image file as is (no encoding required), but I'm not sure using `multipartFormData.append` is a correct solution. Also, when I try to print out the request, I did not see the whole curl command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save the selected image from UIImagePickerController in Directory

```
    func saveUserProfileAtDirectory (userImage : UIImage) -> NSURL {

    let documentsDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
    // create a name for your image
    let imageURL = documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("pic.jpg")

    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(imageURL.path!) {

        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(imageURL.path!)
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    if UIImageJPEGRepresentation(userImage, 1.0)!.writeToFile(imageURL.path!, atomically: true) {

        return imageURL

    } else {
        print("error saving file")
    }

    return NSURL()

}
```

Then use imageURL in almofire:

```
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: imageURL, name: "ISHC_IMAGE_NAME")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I change `multipartFormData.append` by `multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: imageURL, name: "test.jpg")`, it no longer allows me to add headers. It said "[String: String]" is not convertible to HTTPHeaders. Do you know what the correct syntax for this should be?

Comment: So I changed to use the upload file by Alamofire and it worked! Now I just need to clean the image after I upload. Your solution is correct. Thank you!